How to write a parquet file from mongodb using dynamic structure using golang
Im trying to write code using golang to read a collection from mongodb and writing into a parquet file.
As you know, each collection have different structure of data and data types, so the idea is to generate a dynamic structure to write the document into this structure and then create a parquet file and write the data.
Below are my steps

Im connecting to mongodb, read the first document and create a dynamic struct
create a buffer to read each document and insert into the buffer
write the buffer information into a parquet file
close all

But Im trying many formats and I cant write the parquet file. Below is my code
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go-source/local"
    "github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go/parquet"
    "github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go/writer"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

// generate dynamic structure with Parquet tags based on the first document
func DynamicStruct(doc bson.M) reflect.Type {
    fields := make([]reflect.StructField, 0, len(doc))
    for k, v := range doc {
        if k == "_id" {
            continue // Ignore the "_id" field
        }

        var fieldType reflect.Type
        switch v.(type) {
        case string:
            fieldType = reflect.TypeOf("")
        case int, int32, int64:
            fieldType = reflect.TypeOf(int64(0))
        case float32, float64:
            fieldType = reflect.TypeOf(float64(0.0))
        case bool:
            fieldType = reflect.TypeOf(true)
        case []interface{}:
            fieldType = reflect.TypeOf([]interface{}{})
        case map[string]interface{}:
            fieldType = DynamicStruct(v.(bson.M))
        default:
            fieldType = reflect.TypeOf(v)
        }
        fields = append(fields, reflect.StructField{
            Name: getNameUpper(k),
            Type: fieldType,
            Tag:  reflect.StructTag(`parquet:"name=` + k + `, type=` + parquetType(v) + `"`),
        })
    }
    return reflect.PtrTo(reflect.StructOf(fields))
}

func getNameUpper(name string) string {
    return strings.ToUpper(string(name[0])) + name[1:]
}

// return the Parquet type based on the BSON type
func parquetType(value interface{}) string {
    switch value.(type) {
    case string:
        return "BYTE_ARRAY, UTF8"
    case int, int32, int64:
        return "INT64"
    case float32, float64:
        return "DOUBLE"
    case bool:
        return "BOOLEAN"
    case []interface{}:
        return "LIST"
    case map[string]interface{}:
        return "MAP"
    default:
        return "BYTE_ARRAY, UTF8"
    }
}

func main() {
    connectionString := fmt.Sprintf("mongodb://%s:%d", "192.168.88.71", 27017)

    credential_source := options.Credential{
        AuthMechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-1",
        AuthSource:    "admin",
        Username:      "user",
        Password:      "12345678",
    }
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(connectionString).SetAuth(credential_source)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    collection := client.Database("database_name").Collection("collection_name")

    // read 1 document to get the structure
    var doc bson.M
    err = collection.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{}).Decode(&doc)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // generate a dynamic structure with Parquet tags based on the first document
    dynamicType := DynamicStruct(doc)

    // create a dynamic slice
    sliceType := reflect.SliceOf(dynamicType)
    insertManyBuffer := reflect.MakeSlice(sliceType, 0, 10).Interface()

    // read all documents
    cursor, err := collection.Find(ctx, bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer cursor.Close(ctx)

    // append them to the slice
    for cursor.Next(ctx) {
        dynamicValue := reflect.New(dynamicType).Interface()
        if err := cursor.Decode(dynamicValue); err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Decode error", err)
        }

        insertManyBuffer = reflect.Append(reflect.ValueOf(insertManyBuffer), reflect.ValueOf(dynamicValue).Elem()).Interface()
    }

    if err := cursor.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // write to parquet file
    fw, err := local.NewLocalFileWriter("output.parquet")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error local.NewLocalFileWriter - %s", err)
    }

    pw, err := writer.NewParquetWriter(fw, reflect.TypeOf(insertManyBuffer), 4)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error writer.NewParquetWriter - %s", err)
    }

    pw.RowGroupSize = 128 * 1024 * 1024 //128M
    pw.PageSize = 8 * 1024              //8K
    pw.CompressionType = parquet.CompressionCodec_SNAPPY

    if err := pw.Write(insertManyBuffer); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error pw.Write - %s", err)
    }

    if err = pw.WriteStop(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("WriteStop error - %s\n", err)
    }

    fw.Close()

    // print buffer slice
    sliceValue := reflect.ValueOf(insertManyBuffer)
    for i := 0; i < sliceValue.Len(); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Element %d: %+v\n", i, sliceValue.Index(i).Interface())
    }

}


and this an example of 1 document from the collection that Im trying to write into the parquet file dynamically
{
    "_id": ObjectId("66ac54eb3aad5e0b1800bf64"),
    "project_name": "Management System2",
    "start_date": ISODate("2023-01-15T00:00:00Z"),
    "budget": 1000000,
    "project_leader": {
        "name": "Ana Gómez",
        "email": "ana.gomez@example.com",
        "phone": "555-6789"
    },
    "team": [
        {
            "name": "Juancito Ruiz",
            "role": "Developer",
            "full_time": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Laura Castro",
            "role": "Designer",
            "full_time": false
        }
    ],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "title": "Frontend Development",
            "description": "Create the user interface",
            "due_date": ISODate("2023-03-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "status": "In progress",
            "responsible": "Carlos Ruiz"
        },
        {
            "title": "Logo Design",
            "description": "Design the system logo",
            "due_date": ISODate("2023-02-15T00:00:00Z"),
            "status": "Completed",
            "responsible": "Laura Castro"
        }
    ],
    "metadata": {
        "created_by": "admin",
        "creation_date": ISODate("2023-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "last_modified": ISODate("2023-02-01T00:00:00Z")
    }
}

The error is

WriteStop error - runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Could you help me and tell me any recomendation please?
thanks in advance
Im trying to write a parquet file to transform any collection into a parquet file.
Hello Burak, thanks for your reply.
This is the print output (the data and columns name are in spanish, but is the same structure like my previous post)
go run test22.go

WriteStop error - runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
Element 0: &{Nombre_proyecto:Sistema de Gestión Fecha_inicio:1673740800000 Presupuesto:1e+06 Lider_proyecto:map[email:ana.gomez@example.com nombre:Ana Gómez telefono:555-6789] Equipo:[[{Key:nombre Value:Carlos Ruiz} {Key:rol Value:Desarrollador} {Key:tiempo_completo Value:true}] [{Key:nombre Value:Laura Castro} {Key:rol Value:Diseñadora} {Key:tiempo_completo Value:false}]] Tareas:[[{Key:titulo Value:Desarrollo Frontend} {Key:descripcion Value:Crear la interfaz de usuario} {Key:fecha_entrega Value:1677628800000} {Key:estado Value:En progreso} {Key:responsable Value:Carlos Ruiz}] [{Key:titulo Value:Diseño de Logo} {Key:descripcion Value:Diseñar el logotipo del sistema} {Key:fecha_entrega Value:1676419200000} {Key:estado Value:Completada} {Key:responsable Value:Laura Castro}]] Metadata:map[creado_por:admin fecha_creacion:1672531200000 ultima_modificacion:1675209600000]}
Element 1: &{Nombre_proyecto:Sistema de Gestión2 Fecha_inicio:1673740800000 Presupuesto:1e+06 Lider_proyecto:map[email:ana.gomez@example.com nombre:Ana Gómez telefono:555-6789] Equipo:[[{Key:nombre Value:Juancito Ruiz} {Key:rol Value:Desarrollador} {Key:tiempo_completo Value:true}] [{Key:nombre Value:Laura Castro} {Key:rol Value:Diseñadora} {Key:tiempo_completo Value:false}]] Tareas:[[{Key:titulo Value:Desarrollo Frontend} {Key:descripcion Value:Crear la interfaz de usuario} {Key:fecha_entrega Value:1677628800000} {Key:estado Value:En progreso} {Key:responsable Value:Carlos Ruiz}] [{Key:titulo Value:Diseño de Logo} {Key:descripcion Value:Diseñar el logotipo del sistema} {Key:fecha_entrega Value:1676419200000} {Key:estado Value:Completada} {Key:responsable Value:Laura Castro}]] Metadata:map[creado_por:admin fecha_creacion:1672531200000 ultima_modificacion:1675209600000]}
Element 2: &{Nombre_proyecto:Sistema de Ventas Fecha_inicio:1683676800000 Presupuesto:1.5e+06 Lider_proyecto:map[email:mario.perez@example.com nombre:Mario Pérez telefono:555-1234] Equipo:[[{Key:nombre Value:Rosa Martínez} {Key:rol Value:Analista de Datos} {Key:tiempo_completo Value:true}] [{Key:nombre Value:David López} {Key:rol Value:Backend Developer} {Key:tiempo_completo Value:true}]] Tareas:[[{Key:titulo Value:Integración de API} {Key:descripcion Value:Integrar la API de pagos} {Key:fecha_entrega Value:1688169600000} {Key:estado Value:Pendiente} {Key:responsable Value:David López}] [{Key:titulo Value:Análisis de Datos} {Key:descripcion Value:Analizar los datos de ventas} {Key:fecha_entrega Value:1686787200000} {Key:estado Value:En progreso} {Key:responsable Value:Rosa Martínez}]] Metadata:map[creado_por:admin fecha_creacion:1682899200000 ultima_modificacion:1685577600000]}
Element 3: &{Nombre_proyecto:Aplicación Móvil de Fitness Fecha_inicio:1676851200000 Presupuesto:750000 Lider_proyecto:map[email:lucia.torres@example.com nombre:Lucía Torres telefono:555-5678] Equipo:[[{Key:nombre Value:Pedro García} {Key:rol Value:Desarrollador Android} {Key:tiempo_completo Value:true}] [{Key:nombre Value:María Fernández} {Key:rol Value:Diseñadora UX/UI} {Key:tiempo_completo Value:false}]] Tareas:[[{Key:titulo Value:Desarrollo de Interfaz} {Key:descripcion Value:Crear el diseño de la interfaz de la aplicación} {Key:fecha_entrega Value:1680307200000} {Key:estado Value:Completada} {Key:responsable Value:María Fernández}] [{Key:titulo Value:Implementación de Funcionalidades} {Key:descripcion Value:Desarrollar las principales funcionalidades de la app} {Key:fecha_entrega Value:1684108800000} {Key:estado Value:En progreso} {Key:responsable Value:Pedro García}]] Metadata:map[creado_por:admin fecha_creacion:1675987200000 ultima_modificacion:1678838400000]}
Element 4: &{Nombre_proyecto:Plataforma de E-learning Fecha_inicio:1677974400000 Presupuesto:2e+06 Lider_proyecto:map[email:javier.morales@example.com nombre:Javier Morales telefono:555-8910] Equipo:[[{Key:nombre Value:Andrea Navarro} {Key:rol Value:Frontend Developer} {Key:tiempo_completo Value:true}] [{Key:nombre Value:Luis Romero} {Key:rol Value:Administrador de Sistemas} {Key:tiempo_completo Value:true}]] Tareas:[[{Key:titulo Value:Implementación del Backend} {Key:descripcion Value:Configurar y desarrollar el servidor y base de datos} {Key:fecha_entrega Value:1685577600000} {Key:estado Value:Pendiente} {Key:responsable Value:Luis Romero}] [{Key:titulo Value:Diseño de la Plataforma} {Key:descripcion Value:Crear el diseño visual y la arquitectura de la plataforma} {Key:fecha_entrega Value:1682899200000} {Key:estado Value:En progreso} {Key:responsable Value:Andrea Navarro}]] Metadata:map[creado_por:admin fecha_creacion:1677628800000 ultima_modificacion:1680307200000]}
Element 5: &{Nombre_proyecto:Sistema de Gestión de Inventarios Fecha_inicio:1681516800000 Presupuesto:1.2e+06 Lider_proyecto:map[email:elena.vargas@example.com nombre:Elena Vargas telefono:555-4321] Equipo:[[{Key:nombre Value:Fernando Díaz} {Key:rol Value:Especialista en Base de Datos} {Key:tiempo_completo Value:true}] [{Key:nombre Value:Patricia Vega} {Key:rol Value:Consultora de Negocios} {Key:tiempo_completo Value:false}]] Tareas:[[{Key:titulo Value:Desarrollo de Base de Datos} {Key:descripcion Value:Crear y optimizar la base de datos del sistema} {Key:fecha_entrega Value:1688169600000} {Key:estado Value:Pendiente} {Key:responsable Value:Fernando Díaz}] [{Key:titulo Value:Análisis de Requerimientos} {Key:descripcion Value:Recopilar y analizar los requerimientos del cliente} {Key:fecha_entrega Value:1682899200000} {Key:estado Value:Completada} {Key:responsable Value:Patricia Vega}]] Metadata:map[creado_por:admin fecha_creacion:1680307200000 ultima_modificacion:1684108800000]}
Element 6: &{Nombre_proyecto:Portal de Noticias Fecha_inicio:1685577600000 Presupuesto:900000 Lider_proyecto:map[email:ricardo.castillo@example.com nombre:Ricardo Castillo telefono:555-9876] Equipo:[[{Key:nombre Value:Isabel Reyes} {Key:rol Value:Editor de Contenidos} {Key:tiempo_completo Value:true}] [{Key:nombre Value:Miguel Herrera} {Key:rol Value:Desarrollador Web} {Key:tiempo_completo Value:true}]] Tareas:[[{Key:titulo Value:Desarrollo del CMS} {Key:descripcion Value:Implementar el sistema de gestión de contenidos} {Key:fecha_entrega Value:1690848000000} {Key:estado Value:En progreso} {Key:responsable Value:Miguel Herrera}] [{Key:titulo Value:Creación de Contenidos Iniciales} {Key:descripcion Value:Redactar y publicar los primeros artículos} {Key:fecha_entrega Value:1689379200000} {Key:estado Value:Pendiente} {Key:responsable Value:Isabel Reyes}]] Metadata:map[creado_por:admin fecha_creacion:1685577600000 ultima_modificacion:1688169600000]}


Does it print a stack trace? If so, include that stack trace

Hello Burak, thanks for your reply.

There isn't sufficient information in the log. The stack trace appears to be lost before WriteStop returns

thanks, how can I get the stack trace logs, if there are? for more debug

It looks like the panic was recovered in the pw.WriteStop function.
